# Limit count query from column

Tags: mysql

I have query which is going to count which name has some number in field and count how many times is repeats. The result is name with the most count number.

I need to limit this count to 10 or 15 rows now to count, but when i put limit it doesn't work.

```
Select home, count(*) as count
from (select * from results where more='33' and name='FirstName' LIMIT 10) as limit10
group by home
order by count(more) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

I try this with LEAST but its same. I add now order by date, to count exec last rows, but its same...

```
Select home, LEAST( count(*), 12) as count
from (SELECT *,STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum FROM results where more='33' and name='FirstName' ORDER BY datum desc) as limit12
group by home
order by count(more) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How this question was PHP related? Tag removed.

Comment: I think it was suggested.

Comment: what do you mean *it doesn't work*? do you get any errors? or you get the wrong results?

Comment: I when i put LIMIT 10 after 'FirstName' i just got count 1, but there is 9 names in 10 rows. When i delete LIMIT 10, its count me all rows with good results. So i think i didnt configured well LIMIT 10

Comment: So, when you delete the LIMIT 10, the count displays correctly - 9? and you want the max value displayed by count to be 10? (the value you put to the LIMIT clause?)

Comment: No i want to limit rows for count and to count of limited rows, and give me how many time is matches with value more='33'. If Michael has 9 times (value 33 in column more) in 10 rows (this is why I need limit) to show me:
home count
Michael 9

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function:

```
Select home, LEAST( count(*), 10 ) as count
from results where more='33' and name='FirstName'
group by home
order by count(more) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

This would get you the same end result and as an added bonus you get rid of that subquery

Comment: "MySQL doesn't yet support
 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'". LIMIT works fine for subqueries in FROM clause.

Comment: I'm still getting the same results. The limit LEST limit doesn't strict the number or row. Its count the full number of rows even I put 10 or 5

Comment: See my first post. I add my new query with LEAST and order by date